# How to create a combination of sequences using paste

Tags: r

I'm trying create a combination of sequences, such as `c(6:20,26:40)`, from a string. In particular from something like this: `paste(seq(6,26,20), ':', seq(20,40,20))`.

Thanks for any hints on this.

Comment: Please don't sign your posts.  See http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures

Answer (score 0):

Use sep=":" argument

```
paste(c(6,26), c(20,40), sep=":")
```

EDIT 1: I am not sure what you want. If you want to concatenate two series, just use the c() function:

```
unique(c(6:26, 20:40))
```

To generate the sequence using seq, you can use:

```
seq(6, 26)
seq(6, 26, by=1)
seq(6, 26, length=15)  # the 3 expressions are equivalent
```

Comment: Thanks Manuel, but what I need is to persuade the paste generate the appropriate sequence, so that I end up with `(6 7 8 ... 19 20 26 27 .. 39 40)`.

Comment: This would do my thing: `eval(parse(text=paste('c(',paste(c(6,26), c(20,40), sep=":", collapse=','),')')))`

But isn't there anything more parsimonious? :)

Comment: I need to subset my data using a combination of sequences based on `which()`. So I need to create the sequence from something like this: 'paste(which(nettoplan[,1] %in% ukaz) + 2,':',which(nettoplan[,1] %in% ukaz) + 16,sep='',collapse=',')'. The solution i finally arrived to is this: `eval(parse(text=paste('c(',paste(which(nettoplan[,1] %in% ukaz) + 2,':',which(nettoplan[,1] %in% ukaz) + 16,sep='',collapse=','),')')))`. So now I'm just wondering if there is a simpler way..

Comment: Try playing with `do.call` and `get` .  You may be happier with those.  Update: based on your comment w/  nettoplan, if `which(nettoplan[,1] %in% ukaz) + 2` returns a number (or something which can be converted w/ `as.numeric` , then `(which(nettoplan[,1] %in% ukaz) + 2):(which(nettoplan[,1] %in% ukaz) +16)` will produce one of your sequences directly.

Comment: The eval and parse are superfluous.

Comment: Actually, the `which()` returns a vector, that's why I'm using `paste(which(),which())` to get a code giving `length(which())` of sequences. So, I'm trying to get from the point where I have [1] "6:20,26:40,46:60,66:80,86:100,106:120", to produce the series.

Comment: It sounds like you are going from a vector of numbers to a string to an expression and then back to a vector of numbers again.  You can likely avoid all that if you tell us the real problem: the data you are starting with and what you are trying to calculate.

Comment: @RichieCotton: that's what I was trying to tell him.  Heck even some sort of `apply` function that does `pseudoapply(firstwhich,secondwhich, FUN=function(x,y) seq(x,y))` might solve his problem.

Comment: I try differently: The problem is to subset _blocks_ of data, where `which()` returs the first rows of those blocks and `which() + x` the last rows. The `paste(which(), which() + x), sep=":", collapse=',')` then produces a string that looks like the stuff I'd put into c() to get set of row indices for subsetting the data, except its a _string_. So I was asking how to make `c(paste(which(),which() + x), sep=":", collapse=','))` to produce the set of numbers, i.e. how to get `paste()` accepted as a _non-string_.

Comment: @Papa - based on your last comment, you are going about it all wrong.  There are far simpler ways to extract subsets of your data.